# How to configure vim such that it automatically configures itself to fit a particular file type?

Tags: html, vim

As a simple example, when I write my c/c++/java etc on vim, I expect the tab indent to be 4 spaces. However, if I work on a html file, I expect the intent to be 2 spaces. How do I set .vimrc such that it detects what file I am working on and with that information sets itself?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `:help ftplugin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `filetype indent plugin on` will indent automatically based on filetypes using what's in your `indent` folder. There are lots of options that you can manually change (such as `cindent` and the like) but the above command will take care of most of that for you and actually changing `cindent` or `smartindent` yourself can mess things up a bit in my experience.

So, you want your own custom settings for certain files? If you want 2 indents for html files then do this:

1. Put `filetype indent plugin on` in your `.vimrc` file.
2. Create a `html.vim` file.
3. Put the following code in the file:

> setlocal shiftwidth=2
>
> setlocal tabstop=2

4. Save the file to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin`. (If you're on Windows then probably try `$HOME/vimfiles/after/ftplugin`). If that doesn't work then put them in `~/.vim/ftplugin` instead but this last option won't necessarily override other plugins.

---

Here's some more info if people are interested.

There are a number of options for plugins but you specifically asked for edits to the `.vimrc` so you basically need to understand the different types of indents that vim uses. These are the very basic ones. The autoindent options are below.

**Basic**

- `tabstop`, which changes the width of <kbd>tab</kbd>. This is the main value to set.
- `shiftwidth` is all about indentation (e.g. the `>>`, `<<` and `==` commands).
- If you set `expandtab` you will indent `softtabstop` amound of spaces. I.e. `expandtab` converts tabs into a certain number of spaces. I think if you want to insert a block tab instead of a number of spaces when `:set expandtab` is used, you can just enter block visual mode and press tab. For example <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>,<kbd>TAB</kbd>, but I could be wrong.

**Automatic indentation**

- `autoindent` just picks the indentation from previous lines. So if you're working on a line, switch to normal mode and type <kbd>o</kbd> to insert in the line below then you will ident automatically as per the line you were just on.